# connecting multiple boards to one raspberry & design recommendations

Tags: gpio, connection, design

I don't know if it is a good idea to ask these questions here but,

I am planning to design more than one pcb's which sizes and pinouts are the same with rapsberry pi 3 and connect them all together. For example pcb1 will use 3 pins on pi, and pcb2 will use other 2 pins on pi. pcb 1 is on top of the pi, think that pi's i/o pins are long enough, and pcb2 will be on the pcb1 and so on.

It will be something like that http://www.harrowalsh.de/Elektronik/APPLEBOX/Gameport/web/16GameportIOPiggypack_plugedinLeftside.jpg

My questions are,

1) is it a good idea to do that? what is your recommendations?

2) i will change the raspberry pi gpio pins with the long ones. but which connector can i use in the other pcb's?

3) do you have an another idea to connect 2-3-4 small pcb modules to pi? think that these pcb modules are selectable for users. In one design, user can use pcb2&pcb3 and pcb2&pcb4 in another design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to is called "Stacking". Provided that your board pins do not interfere with each other and/or you provide addressable boards (e.g. SPI or I2C), you're okay stacking them.

And **NO**, you do **NOT** replace your Pi's GPIO headers with freakishly long ones. See below:

1. It's not a bad idea. It's supported by some boards.
2. Don't do that. The usual solution is to use a stacking header. Do the same to PCB 2 to allow another PCB to go on top of it.
3. See answer #2. It also depends on how you make your boards, but I think an addressable solution will be better (if not the only way).

Click on the image to zoom in.
[image]

Picture is from this link. You can read through it: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-pwm-servo-hat-for-raspberry-pi/stacking-hats

Comment: Further to this, it may be useful to review the [design guidelines for Pi HATS](https://github.com/raspberrypi/hats/blob/master/designguide.md).

Comment: Yes, i read it.